Get list of kwargs for parent class
For some Python packages, it will fetch and display a list of kwargs for a class, even if it is an inherited class.
The following is an example of code that inherits Django's model class.
I named the arg of the class as **kwargs, but vscode takes the kwargs of the parent class and shows it.
How do I use this feature?
Please check the following image.


With that __init__ method the effective signature is correct, isn't it?

Since you're passing the arguments to the parent's method, it assumes that the all the same keywords can be used.

I deliberately declared **kwargs in __init__().
The reason is to show that it is nevertheless fetching and displaying the parent class's kwargs(verbose_name, name, primary_key, ..).
How is this work possible? I would like to use this feature. @KlausD. @Barmer

Your IDE seems to be smarter than you think.
